# How do I add a handler to a WPF DataGridCell ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

I have this XAML:

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Vessel}" Header="Vessel" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem x:Name="mVesselSize" Header="Size"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

When I try to add a Click handler to the menu, I get:

'mVesselSize_Click' is not valid. 'Click' is not an event on 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn'.

What am I doing wrong? I think it might be to do with the menu being inside a DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle (I copied that code from somewhere else on stack overflow) but I don't know how else to make a context menu for a particular data grid cell (column).

Answer (score 0):

Seems cannot set event handler in style setter for ContextMenu

This is a hacky way follow your thoughts

```
<MenuItem x:Name="mVesselSize" Header="Size">
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
           <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="mVesselSize_Click"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
 </MenuItem>
```

But there will definitely be better solutions

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but I am getting an error "The member "Style" is not recognized or is not accessible.". I pasted the <MenuItem.Style> block under the <MenuItem> just as you have it, and didn't change anything else. Is that correct?